# How to prevent from clickjacking attack in angular-4 application?

Tags: angular

I want to stop my angular application to be open in an IFRAME.
I read some article on google and came to know that in order to achieve this we have to set X-Frame-Options. But I did not find the way to give this header.

Can anyone help me that how can I achieve this in angular-4?

Comment: Where the app is been hosted?

Comment: My app is hosted on IIS. Please let me know if you need any other details in order to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to do with angular app. It is a setting in IIS. To set `X-Frame-Options` in IIS server, do the following,

1. Open IIS.
2. Select the site that you want to set the `X-Frame-Options`.
3. Double-click the HTTP Response Headers icon in the right middle pane where options are displayed.
4. Click Add link in the Action panel to add the header. Type `X-Frame-Options` in the
   Name field and type `SAMEORIGIN in the Value field.
5. Click OK to save your changes.

More detail about clickjacking attack is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/)

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for Angular:-

http://taimooradilbadshah.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-clickjacking-attack-and-x-frame.html

I made a web.config file on server(IIS) where I put my build(dist) code.

It also works for Angular routing (ignore using hash tag(#)).

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
              <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
            </customHeaders>
         </httpProtocol>

        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/angularProject/index.html" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

You can check it here your website after putting above code :-

https://www.lookout.net/test/clickjack.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is by using the X-Frame-Options with the same origin.
But for the workaround, you can use this document
**https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html**
this tells how you can add the script to your application
For using this in angular you can call a function from the constructor of the app.component.ts file

```
checkAntiClickJacking() {
     if (self !== top) {
       // Redirect to your url
     }
}
```